# EBX register is used for passing a __fastcall function parameter

Tags: assembly, visual-c++, x86, calling-convention

I am trying to hook a fastcall function that uses EBX and been trying to re-produce the same asm lines in order to make the hook work

```
mov ebx,dword ptr ss:[ebp+8]
mov ecx,eax
call 004F00F0
```

Any idea what would make a __fastcall calling convention make a use of EBX?
Note: The written asm is generated by visual studio c++ 2005 compiler and I am writing my own code on vs2019.

**UPDATE #1:**

The function assembly is as following,

```
sub esp,8
test ecx,ecx
push ebp
push esi
push edi
je 004F0208
mov ax,word ptr ds:[ecx+80]
test al,2
je 004F0208
and al,1C
cmp al,4
jne 004F0208
fldz 
lea ebp,dword ptr ds:[ebx+21A0]
fst dword ptr ss:[ebp+8],st(0)
mov dword ptr ss:[ebp],0
fst dword ptr ss:[ebp+C],st(0)
mov byte ptr ss:[ebp+4],0
mov byte ptr ss:[ebp+5],0
xor eax,eax
mov dword ptr ss:[ebp+10],eax
mov dword ptr ss:[ebp+14],eax
mov dword ptr ss:[ebp+18],eax
mov dword ptr ss:[ebp+1C],eax
mov dword ptr ss:[ebp+20],eax
mov dword ptr ss:[ebp+24],eax
mov dword ptr ss:[ebp+28],eax
mov dword ptr ss:[ebp+2C],eax
mov dword ptr ss:[ebp+30],eax
mov dword ptr ss:[ebp],ecx
mov byte ptr ds:[ebx+21A4],1
movzx eax,word ptr ds:[ecx+E4]
mov dword ptr ss:[esp+10],eax
lea esi,dword ptr ds:[ebx+1EC]
mov edi,17
fild st(0),dword ptr ss:[esp+10]
fstp dword ptr ds:[ebx+21A8],st(0)
movzx ecx,word ptr ds:[ecx+E6]
mov dword ptr ss:[esp+10],ecx
push ecx
fild st(0),dword ptr ss:[esp+14]
fstp dword ptr ds:[ebx+21AC],st(0)
fstp dword ptr ss:[esp],st(0)
push 0
push 3
call 004B3510
fldz 
push ecx
fstp dword ptr ss:[esp],st(0)
push 0
push 3
mov edi,18
call 004B3510
mov edx,dword ptr ds:[ebx]
mov eax,dword ptr ds:[edx+4E8]
mov ecx,ebx
call eax
push 3207
call 00430A00
add esp,4
mov esi,eax
lea ecx,dword ptr ds:[ebx+8]
push ecx
lea eax,dword ptr ds:[edi-14]
mov ecx,esi
call 00404090
mov edi,00CD3A80
call 0042C8F0
cmp dword ptr ss:[ebp],0
je 004F01F3
mov eax,edi
mov ecx,ebp
call 004DD6B0
mov edi,esi
mov eax,edi
mov esi,00CD3A80
call 0042C820
mov esi,ebx
call 00484D90
pop edi
pop esi
pop ebp
add esp,8
ret
```

Comment: Are you sure that `ebx` is actually used as an argument? What does the prototype for that function look like? What does its (assembly) implementation look like?

Comment: @Michael yeah, ebx is actually used within the function, I have added the function asm to the question

Comment: That sounds like a custom calling convention, not pure `__fastcall`.  Are you sure it wasn't hand-written asm?  If not, generated from what source?

Comment: @PeterCordes the source code isn't really available as far as i am aware the executable was compiled on vs c++ 2005 and no, i do not really think it's a hand written asm but as you have mentioned it might be a custom calling convention!

Comment: Could some of it be an inline asm statement?  The code-gen choices look weird.  I don't have experience looking at VS2005's output, but `mov dword ptr ss:[ebp],0` / ... / `xor eax,eax` / `mov dword ptr ss:[ebp+10],eax` / ... more stores of EAX looks really suspicious. It makes sense for a compiler to zero a register and store that, saving 4 bytes per instruction. If if you're going to do that in a block, why not do so even earlier?  Unless there are multiple branch targets in that block so it's *not* a basic block, maybe?  But you could probably still move the xor-zeroing earlier, if not later

Comment: Maybe that's just normal missed optimizations / braindead code from old MSVC, but it made me wonder if some of those instructions could be from inline asm.  (And maybe this was using some super hacky unsafe communication mechanism where something puts a pointer in EBX before a call, and an asm statement in the function assumes the compiler hasn't stepped on it?  IDK, that's a stretch.)  Seems unlikely that MSVC could really generate code for custom calling conventions, though; that normally requires hand-written asm.